# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection NodeJS MSSQL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express, promise

I'm having a play about testing out some NodeJS setting up an API.

However when SQL returns an error about NULL columns my http call just hangs and you can see the error in the node console.

The error I get is

> node:7397) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 2): RequestError: Cannot insert the value
>   NULL into column 'FeatureEntryId', table 'testdb
>   STING.dbo.J_ProductFeaturesRelation'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails."

In understand the SQL error and that's fine I just want NodeJS to return this error message to the client.

Here is the code.

```
//Add or update feature relations
var insertFeatureRelation = (callback, productid, featureid) => {
    console.log(productid + ' ' + featureid)
    var conn = new sql.Connection(settings.dbConfig())
    conn.connect().then(function (conn) {
        var request = new sql.Request(conn);
        request.input('productid', sql.VarChar, productid);
        request.input('featureid', sql.VarChar, featureid);
        request.execute('PM_InsertFeatureRelation').then(function (recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
            callback(recordsets)
        })
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('ffs');
        callback(null, err);
    });
}
exports.insertFeatureRelation = function (req, resp, productid, featureid) {
    insertFeatureRelation(function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err)
        } else {
            httpMsgs.sendJSON(req, resp, data)
        }
        resp.end();
    }, productid, featureid)
};
```

The code works fine if the stored procedure runs fine however the error just never actually somes through to the page.

Here is the content of the httpMsgs:

```
exports.show500 = function(req, resp, err) {
    console.log('heree')
        resp.writeHeader(500, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        resp.write(JSON.stringify({data: "Error:" + err}))
};

exports.sendJSON = function(req, resp, data) {
    if (data){
        resp.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        resp.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @MrJLP Why does httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err) not fire if SQL returns an error. I would have thought it would have caught the error in the catch and then run the console.log('ffs') and the callback.

Comment: the promise that fail is `request.execute('PM_InsertFeatureRelation')` which you don't have a catch for it.

Comment: @naortor - Awesome thanks! I understand more now. The catch in the above code will only fire if the connection to SQL is not possible, so I added a catch onto the request.execute promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference... The reason node hung was because the error from SQL was never caught in the catch of the execute function.

Here is the updated code.

```
//Add or update feature relations
var insertFeatureRelation = (callback, productid, featureid) => {
    console.log(productid + ' ' + featureid)
    var conn = new sql.Connection(settings.dbConfig())
    conn.connect().then(function (conn) {
        var request = new sql.Request(conn);
        request.input('productid', sql.VarChar, productid);
        request.input('featureid', sql.VarChar, featureid);
        request.execute('PM_InsertFeatureRelation').then(function (recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
            callback(recordsets)
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(null, err);
        })
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(null, err);
    });
}
exports.insertFeatureRelation = function (req, resp, productid, featureid) {
    insertFeatureRelation(function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err)
        } else {
            httpMsgs.sendJSON(req, resp, data)
        }
        resp.end();
    }, productid, featureid)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Adam91Holt's answer is OK, it can be further simplified as

```
var insertFeatureRelation = (callback, productid, featureid) => {
    console.log(productid + ' ' + featureid)
    var conn = new sql.Connection(settings.dbConfig())
    conn.connect().then(function (conn) {
        var request = new sql.Request(conn);
        request.input('productid', sql.VarChar, productid);
        request.input('featureid', sql.VarChar, featureid);
        return request.execute('PM_InsertFeatureRelation');
    }).then(function (recordsets) {
        callback(recordsets);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(null, err);
    });
}
```

Benefit is that there is a single point of error handling

To be honest though, I wouldn't use callback paradigm with promises unless I had to

```
var insertFeatureRelation = (productid, featureid) => {
    console.log(productid + ' ' + featureid)
    var conn = new sql.Connection(settings.dbConfig())
    conn.connect().then(function (conn) {
        var request = new sql.Request(conn);
        request.input('productid', sql.VarChar, productid);
        request.input('featureid', sql.VarChar, featureid);
        return request.execute('PM_InsertFeatureRelation');
    });
}
exports.insertFeatureRelation = function (req, resp, productid, featureid) {
    insertFeatureRelation(productid, featureid).then(function(data) {
        httpMsgs.sendJSON(req, resp, data)
        resp.end();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err)
        resp.end();
    });
};
```